# Find an implicit function $H(x,y)=c$ on which the trajectories of $\frac{dx}{dt}=2y+xy^2, \frac{dy}{dt}=8x-y^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find an implicit function $H(x,y)=c$ on which the trajectories of $\frac{dx}{dt}=2y+xy^2, \frac{dy}{dt}=8x-y^3$.

I am studying for my qualifying exams and this problem came up. I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: is there a reason why such an invariant $H$ should exist?

Comment: @abel Indeed. The phase diagram of the system shows that most trajectories "escape to infinity", a fact which severely restricts the candidates for such an invariant.

Comment: the divergence of the vector field is $(2y+xy^2)_x + (8x-y^3)_y = -2y^2$ so does not bendixon's criteria rule any closed orbits? have only the origin, a hyperbolic fixed point only goes to confirm that.

Comment: @abel On the other hand, the absence of closed orbits does not prevent the existence of an invariant H... :-)

Comment: @Saif were you able to obtain the official solution? Based on the lengthy, but now deleted, discussions/ideas with other members, I'm pretty sure such a solution doesn't exist.

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't. This was a question, word for word from a qualifying exam a few years ago.

Comment: I wonder who deleted the lengthy discussion of Agunra R's possible solution? If you try to push the idea used in that solution further, you would be able to show there doesn't exist such function $H(x,y)=c$. Note that my proof requires A and B are constants (in fact, this is the only possible case!) due to the way he set up the equations to solve for each partial derivative.

Comment: @user177196 Actually, what you call "possible solution" does not go very far since, once straightened up, it simply says that every solution $H$ is such that $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=(y^3-8x)\cdot L(x,y),\quad\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}=(2y+xy^2)\cdot L(x,y),$$ for some unknown function $L$. And now what? We know this is impossible with $L$ some nonzero constant but some cleverly chosen, nonconstant, function $L$ could yield a nontrivial invariant $H$ of the dynamics.

Comment: @Did it is possible that such L doesn't exist.

Comment: @user177196 Beware that to exist and to admit a simple analytical form are two different notions. Assume for example that every solution $(x(t),y(t))$ meets the $x$-axis exactly once, then define $H$ by the condition that the solution starting from $(x,y)$ meets the $x$-axis at $(H(x,y),0)$ (for example, $H(x,0)=x$). Thus $H$ would *exist* but we would have no (general) formula for $H$.

Comment: @Did the main issue is: how do we know such a solution $(x(t), y(t))$ exists, and whether they meet the x-axis exactly once?

Comment: @user177196 No, this was just an example to explain concretely that H might exist, but be intractable.

Answer (score 1):

**1st hint:** from the two equations, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8x-y^3}{2y+xy^2}$. Solving this DE may be quite difficult, but you may want to try:)

**2nd hint:** We have $y\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}=2x^2+8y^2$. Thus $(xy)'= 2x^2+8y^2$. By integrating both sides, we get $xy=\frac{2x^3}{3}+ \frac{8y^3}{3}$? (*Edit:* and **actually we don't**...)

Comment: I that is the point I got to as well. But I figured it was the incorrect path because of how horrendous it is.

Comment: "By integrating both sides", we do not get what you write.

Comment: @Did: that's why I left the question mark at the end...

Comment: No. If one writes "hint", one states that the approach DOES lead to a solution. Otherwise, one is taking the risk to send the hapless OP into a dead-end. Are you saying you knowingly took that risk in the present case?

Comment: @Did: yeap... my bad:P

Comment: @Did: were you able to prove that there doesn't exist such function $H(x,y)=c$ based on the ideas of Agunra's R possible solution, which was once posted but deleted two weeks ago?

Comment: @user177196 No, see my comment to the main question.